# Ruby: Populate variables by Iterating thru Nested Hash File

Tags: ruby, file, hash, syntax, nested

Given the following Nested Hash File:

```
SQL_LIST_ODS = {

foo_TableA: {
  load_mode: "do_whatever1",
  query: <<EOS,
  select foo1, foo2, foo3 from foo_TableA
EOS
}

foo_TableB: {
  load_mode: "do_whatever2",
  query: <<EOS,
  select foo1, foo2, foo3 from foo_TableB
EOS
}

}
```

Need to perform various tasks based on the value of #{load_mode} (e.g. either "do_whatever1" or "do_whatever2".  Here is a snippet of what I have so far...

```
require "./eas_etl_ods-oltp1_fulltbl_sql_ods.rb"
...
sql_list = SQL_LIST_ODS.dup   # from separate sql file

sql_list.each_pair do # ***OR*** should this be sql_list.each do (vs each_pair)?
  <<<insert logic here -- see notes below>>>
end
```

Here is the basic logic we need to perform (pseudo code):

- Test if #{load_mode} == "do_whatever1" then do something with #{query}.
- Else do something else with #{query}.

Can you help verify the Nested Hash File and complete the snippet w/ correct syntax?

Comment: You first need to correct your syntax by adding a comma after the first element of `SQL_LIST_ODS`.  When asking a question it's always a good idea to make sure that code you expect to run actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma between the foo_Tables.

Then try:

```
sql_list.each do |key, value|
  if value[:load_mode] == "do_whatever1"
    # do something with value[:query]
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

If you want to be compatible with ruby 1.8, use this syntax:

```
SQL_LIST_ODS = {

:foo_TableA => {
  :load_mode => "do_whatever1",
  :query => <<EOS,
  select foo1, foo2, foo3 from foo_TableA
EOS
},

:foo_TableB => {
  :load_mode => "do_whatever2",
  :query => <<EOS,
  select foo1, foo2, foo3 from foo_TableB
EOS
},

}
```

Comment: I believe the asker was using the `key: value` syntax that was introduced in v1.9.

Comment: This answer is correct except for the bit about the hash syntax (other than the missing comma). I would vote up if not for that.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware there was any new syntax for hashes. Grew up with 1.8.x :-)  Answer edited.

Comment: AWESOME -- Thanks for the incredibly fast and perfect answer.  Make it a Great Day :)